# What the most reliable way to determine whether user visited page from mobile phone?

Tags: javascript

What the most reliable way to determine whether a user visited a page from a mobile phone using JS?

I need somehow determine whether page rendering happens on phone screen or not. If it's happening on phone's screen I need to show different UI controls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if the web page is visited by a phone browser or a PC browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699555/how-to-check-if-the-web-page-is-visited-by-a-phone-browser-or-a-pc-browser)

Comment: Common practice is to use the user agent

Answer (score 0):

You can use [user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent) and parse it to find out whether it's mobile or not *OR* you can  go with CSS and make use of [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)